# Windows 7 - netsh wlan show profiles: Access is denied

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, cmd.exe, netsh

If I try to run the command

```
netsh wlan show profiles
```

I receive the error:

```
Function WlanGetProfileList returns error 5:
Access is denied
```

This happens regardless if I run the command prompt as an administrator. 
Any help?

Comment: run Proces Monitor in background while executing the command. Now look in the log for ACCESS DENIED entries in the RESULT column: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-3-Process-Monitor, http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-4-Process-Monitor

Comment: @magicandre1981 It's saying "SUCCESS" for the netsh.exe processes

Comment: do you see other ACCESS DENIED errors for other processes?

Comment: @magicandrew Yeah svchost.exe runs CreateFile and it fails with ACCESS DENIED. The exact command is 
`C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe -k LocalSystemNetworkRestricted`

Also chrome spams ACCESS DENIEDs at me every few seconds but I don't think that's related. (The  operation is `RegOpenKey`

Comment: which key do the 2 other processes try to open?

Comment: Which two processes? netsh.exe opens thousands of keys and most fail with `NAME NOT FOUND`.

Comment: svchost.exe and Chrome

Comment: svchost.exe doesn't open a key is runs CreateFile. Chrome also wasn't opening a key, but it's not doing it anymore and I forget exactly what is was doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
netsh wlan delete filter permission=denyall networktype=infrastructure
```

and

```
netsh wlan delete filter permission=denyall networktype=adhoc
```

Comment: `The filter does not exist on the system` is the response I get from both commands

Comment: @MicroGodrad WLAN AutoConfig service run?

Comment: `Auto configuration logic is enabled on interface "Wireless Network Connection"` is the response I get.